# Is 'Running Ragged' being awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The description states:

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

---

I have 3 questions:

- Does this mean that if I earn 150 reputation combined on 3 sites, eg. 100 rep on Meta Stack Exchange and 50 rep on Ask Different, I would get this badge?
- Does Meta Stack Exchange count?
- Is this being awarded now since it states 'within 15 days'?

Comment: *No.* I think it means 150 on each site other than SO. I hope I am wrong. :P

Comment: @TAsk Yea, that was what I thought after re-reading it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Answer is now mod-approved.*

> Does this mean that if I earn 150 reputation combined on 3 sites, eg. 100 rep on Meta Stack Exchange and 50 rep on Ask Different, I would get this badge?

No, you have to get 150 rep on each of the sites.  Otherwise, it would say earn 150 reputation points on three sites combined, not three different sites.

> Does Meta Stack Exchange count?

Yes.

> Is this being awarded now since it states 'within 15 days'?

It is only awarded for 15 consecutive days *within the hatting period.*

Comment: Saw the feed in chat.  ;)

Comment: yeah it's the intersection of the last 15 days and the winterbash period

Comment: Answer mod approved.  ;)

Comment: @Sklivvz how often does this script run? I figured that I should be eligible for the hat(s) yesterday already (after gaining +150 on Meta SE, Puzzling and ELL).

Comment: In case there are any doubts left: [I got the hat today with Meta SE being one of the contributing sites](//i.stack.imgur.com/524re.png).